# Trigger Openlayers Fullscreen Map

Tags: openlayers-3

Hi is there a way to trigger the fullscreen map on Openlayers? I know there's a control that we can add on the map to trigger the fullscreen. But I'm wondering if there are functions that I can use to make my Map display in fullscreen Mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the respective method on the getTargetElement of the map, so for instance:

```
var element = map.getTargetElement();
if (element.requestFullscreen) {
  element.requestFullscreen();
} else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
  element.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```